# Routes not working on first visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a namespace and I just added edit and update to the routes file for a particular model. My problem is when I visit the edit route from a link_to within the app, it says No route found, however, if I manually enter the same url it finds it and renders the page properly. The url i am trying to visit is `coordinator/teacher_recommendation/?/edit`
show works just fine.

Here is the relevant part of my routes file:

```
 namespace :coordinator do
   resources :applicants, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :index] do
     member do
       get 'invite_teachers'
       put 'create_invitations'
     end
   end
   resources :teacher_recommendations, :only => [:show, :edit, :update] do
     resources :recommendation_reminders, :only => [:create, :new, :update]
   end  
 end
```

Any ideas on why this would be?

Here is the button_to link which does not work:

```
button_to "Send Reminder", edit_coordinator_teacher_recommendation_path(@applicant.science_recommendation)
```

And here is the link_to that does work:

```
link_to "Send Reminder", edit_coordinator_teacher_recommendation_path(@applicant.science_recommendation)
```

Comment: Can you run firebug or the Chrome Developer Tools to see the exact URL that's being requested in both cases? Perhaps there's something subtly different about them. Also, if you use the link_to after manually visiting the link, does it work?

Comment: run `rake routes` and paste it here. also, please paste your `<%= link_to EDIT link_path_goes_here %>`

Comment: Post the code for the `link_to` method you're using.

Comment: Exact same URL, once it goes to the url and reports that there was no route found, I can put cursor in the address bar and hit enter and it renders the page normally. And no, can't use the link_to after manually visiting the page either. Also if i use the refresh and confirm resubmission it won't work. It seems like it must be an issue with the post...

Comment: Ok.. correction. The link is a "button_to" link. When I change it to a link_to, the page renders correctly. What is the difference in link_to and button_to?

Comment: This works: <%= link_to "Send Reminder", edit_coordinator_teacher_recommendation_path(@applicant.science_recommendation) %>         This doesn't: <%= button_to "Send Reminder", edit_coordinator_teacher_recommendation_path(@applicant.science_recommendation) %>

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question. Post it as an answer, and then you can accept your answer to mark this question "solved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the button_to link to have a method parameter and this seemed to take care of the problem...

> button_to "Send Reminder", edit_coordinator_teacher_recommendation_path(@applicant.science_recommendation), class: "btn btn-mini", :method => :get %>